# What is the context of With hardship comes ease?

Tags: quran, tafseer

I'm curious about the verse.
It's obvious that hardship refers to life here on earth but what about the ease part? Does it refer to a believer's life on earth in the later years or when resurrected in the afterlife?

Answer (score -2):

https://islam4u.pro/blog/surah-inshirah/#ease-accompanies-hardship

This link explains it nicely.

Comment: This is a link only post in the answer section. We expect answers to be well elaborated, in your own words in the "answer section" and fully address the inquiry, not linked. See also in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/are-link-only-answers-acceptable-here)